# How can I find text between two headings from docx in python

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, spacy

I want to extract information from the resume, for this, I have to identify headings and take text data underneath that heading.

Comment: Hey Muneeb, could you please be a little bit more specific in your question? i.e. What have you already tried? A bit more context would be really nice.

Comment: Hey chris, Actually I am working on resume parsing in NLP using python. I have taken resume in word (docx) format and converted to plain text. I want to extract information from  Education History (Heading) which includes degree title, institution name, CGPA and location. If I recognize heading, i can extract above mention infromation under the heading.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck. If you're unsure how refer [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be more specific to your issue and approach you want to take. As of now, for heading extraction, you can define a corpus first form all the headings after reading in beautiful soup. Once such corpus is created you can now match the corpus with heading of the resume and get the section by defining the starting and ending data point. and then match skills et. whatever you want to do with it. 
This is the simplest approach based on your current question. Be more specific so, i can guide with more precise approach.

Best,